# Websocket atmosphere: handle 302 status code

Tags: javascript, websocket, atmosphere

I use atmosphere both in client and server side to use websockets. I can restart my server and then the current user sessions can be erased or not.

When I erase user sessions and js-client atmosphere websocket tries to establish connection, it receives the 302 code:

```
blob:http://servername:8888/eb2199e1-9415-4487-bb78-2c8fda726878:164
WebSocket connection to 'ws://servername:8888/xxx/yyy/atmosphere/handler?X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=5541fb00-9391-435e-bbf9-d835870986d4&X-Atmosphere-Framework=2.3.5-javascript&X-Atmosphere-Transport=websocket&X-Atmosphere-TrackMessageSize=true&Content-Type=application/json&X-atmo-protocol=true' failed:
Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 302
WrappedWebSocket
```

It is ok from the server logic to send 302. However, in JS code I need somehow to handle this case and make proper logic (show user a message, redirect to login page, etc).

The question is: do atmosphere framework have any possibilities to handle this case and if yes, which are they?

Because after that I only have the following calls and nothing more. I receive no callbacks in atmosphere listeners, which I have registered.

```
Atmosphere: websocket.onerror
Atmosphere: websocket.onclose
```